# execute SSIS package

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

Is it possible to execute a SSIS package in C# Code ? We can process cube using the namespace "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient". What will be namespace/method to be used for executing a package/task, if possible? This considers Script Task too, in SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Running a Package Programmatically on the Local Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx) from msdn

Comment: How do we perform the execution of a particular control flow task in C# ? Is it possible to change the SSIS variable in C# code just like we perform in Script Task, using the instance of Application class ?

Answer (score 0):

The way we do this is we call a stored procedure from code and this stored procedure runs the SSIS package.

```
DECLARE @Command varchar(500);

SET @Command = 'dtexec /FILE "<SSIS File Name Goes Here>" /Decrypt "<Password Here>"';

EXEC msdb..xp_cmdshell @Command
```